# group Items by column and order by other column

Tags: mysql

I have table as below , I want to take latest rating for the client
basically user whenever updates rating, count will be incremented and a entry will be made in table. Table goes as below

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|_id| name   | client_id | user_id | rating | count |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1  | Four   |   1       |    1    |   4    |   1   |
|2  | three  |   1       |    1    |   3    |   2   |
|3  | two    |   1       |    1    |   2    |   3   |
|4  | five   |   1       |    1    |   5    |   4   |
|5  | two    |   1       |    2    |   2    |   1   |
|6  | three  |   1       |    2    |   3    |   2   |
|7  | two    |   2       |    1    |   2    |   1   |
|8  | three  |   2       |    1    |   3    |   2   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

For rating of `client_id 1` I want out put like

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|_id| name   | client_id | user_id | rating | count |
-----------------------------------------------------
|4  | five   |   1       |    1    |   5    |   4   |
|6  | three  |   1       |    2    |   3    |   2   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

so far I tried `SELECT * FROM test
where client_id = 1 group by client_id order by count desc;`
but not getting expected result, any help??

Comment: Why `_id=5` should not be there in the result ?

Comment: because its count related to the user_id 2 is 1, so _id 6 because its count is 2 which is max for the client_id 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `left join` on the same table as

```
select t1.* from test t1 
left join test t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
and t1.client_id = t2.client_id 
and t1._id < t2._id 
where 
t2._id is null 
and t1.client_id = 1 
order by t1.`count` desc;
```

Using un-correlated subquery you may do as

```
select t1.* from test t1 
join ( 
  select max(_id) as _id,
  client_id,
  user_id 
  from test 
  where client_id = 1 
  group by client_id,user_id 
)t2 
on t1._id = t2._id 
and t1.client_id = t2.client_id 
order by t1.`count` desc;
```

UPDATE : From the comment how to join another table into above , for this here is an example

```
mysql> select * from users ;
+------+------+
| _id  | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | AAA  |
|    2 | BBB  |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+-------+-----------+---------+--------+-------+
| _id  | name  | client_id | user_id | rating | count |
+------+-------+-----------+---------+--------+-------+
|    1 | four  |         1 |       1 |      4 |     1 |
|    2 | three |         1 |       1 |      3 |     2 |
|    3 | two   |         1 |       1 |      2 |     3 |
|    4 | five  |         1 |       1 |      5 |     4 |
|    5 | two   |         1 |       2 |      2 |     1 |
|    6 | three |         1 |       2 |      3 |     2 |
|    7 | two   |         2 |       1 |      2 |     1 |
|    8 | three |         2 |       1 |      3 |     2 |
+------+-------+-----------+---------+--------+-------+

select t1.*,u.name from test t1 
join users u on u._id = t1.user_id
left join test t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
and t1.client_id = t2.client_id 
and t1._id < t2._id 
where 
t2._id is null 
and t1.client_id = 1 
order by t1.`count` desc;
```

Will give you

```
+------+-------+-----------+---------+--------+-------+------+
| _id  | name  | client_id | user_id | rating | count | name |
+------+-------+-----------+---------+--------+-------+------+
|    4 | five  |         1 |       1 |      5 |     4 | AAA  |
|    6 | three |         1 |       2 |      3 |     2 | BBB  |
+------+-------+-----------+---------+--------+-------+------+
```

Note that the join to `users` table is inner join and this will require all the user to be preset in `users` table which are in `test` table

If some users are missing in the `users` table then use `left join` this will have null values for the data selected from `users` table.

Comment: thanks, I got expected result, wont there any other simple query??

Comment: Well these are the most simple available :)  And its highly recommended https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: and I want to get user information also from user table using user_id how could I do that using your query,  basically user is another table

Comment: Just add a join to user table and select the fields you want to select from users table. If the table name is `users` then it will be in the first case as `join users u on u.user_id = t1.user_id` before the first left join, and in the 2nd case it would be same before the `join (....)`

Comment: I am trying like this


select t1.* , u.* from test t1
join users u on u._id = t1.user_id
left join test t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
and t1.client_id = t2.client_id 
and t1._id < t2._id 
where 
t2._id is null 
and t1.client_id = 1 
order by t1.`count` desc;


but not getting expected result

Comment: It should work let me check. Need to make sure that user table has all the users as in your test table, since its an inner join

Comment: thank you :) Abhik Chakraborty, I was using wrong id that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like

```
select _id, name, client_id, user_id, rating, max(count)
from clients 
group by client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
SELECT * FROM test
where client_id = 1 
group by user_id 
order by count desc
```

Comment: I tried this no use, I also mentioned in my question